# Programmatically start server and deploy API

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core (C#) and creating an API. Based on our application we know when we will have high and low times, so we want to preemptively start up servers with extra api endpoints. Is there a way to programmatically deploy a new server with the API started and ready to go?

We will have one (admin/master) server constantly running that will handle the deployments probably watching with a cron job.

Any tips would be helpful. Do we create a base server that gets cloned? Do we have our API in a zip that needs to get uploaded?

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about auto-scaling.  Are you using Azure? Then you'd just need to [configure it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview).

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks. I'll look into that to see if i can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you could try to use VMSS to enable auto-scale.

Virtual machine scale sets are an Azure compute resource that you can use to deploy and manage a set of identical VMs. With all VMs configured the same, scale sets are designed to support true autoscale, and no pre-provisioning of VMs is required. So it's easier to build large-scale services that target big compute, big data, and containerized workloads.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview).

> Is there a way to programmatically deploy a new server with the API started and ready to go?

As far as I know, we have multiple ways to deploy a new VM and start it.

I suggest you could use azure fluent api or azure template deploy by using C# codes to do it.

More details, you could refer to this [fluent code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-dotnet-manage-vm).

Notice: No matter use fluent api or azure template, you need firstly create an Azure Active Directory application and service principal. After you generate the service principal, you could get the applicationid,access key and talentid. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).

> Do we create a base server that gets cloned? Do we have our API in a zip that needs to get uploaded?

In my opinion, I suggest you could create a managed image of your current VM.

The image can then be used to create multiple VMs by using fluent api or azure template deploy. All of these VMs will have same C disk, so it will contains all the same setting.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.You could firstly install and set your VM.

2.You could follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource) to create image.

After creating image, you will find the image resource as below:

[image]

3.Click the image resource and create a VM.

[image]

4.Notice:You need select the same network security group as your base VM's network security group.

[image]

5.Download the template.

[image]

6.Then you could use the C# codes to deploy the VM by using the template.

Codes as below:

```
// Requires the following Azure NuGet packages and related dependencies:
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Authorization" version="2.0.0"
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.4.0-preview"
// package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.8-preview"

using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PortalGenerated
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a helper class for deploying an Azure Resource Manager template
    /// More info about template deployments can be found here https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/?LinkID=733371
    /// </summary>
    class DeploymentHelper
    {
        string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
        string clientId = "your-service-principal-clientId";
        string clientSecret = "your-service-principal-client-secret";
        string resourceGroupName = "resource-group-name";
        string deploymentName = "deployment-name";
        string resourceGroupLocation = "resource-group-location"; // must be specified for creating a new resource group
        string pathToTemplateFile = "path-to-template.json-on-disk";
        string pathToParameterFile = "path-to-parameters.json-on-disk";
        string tenantId = "tenant-id";

        public async void Run()
        {
            // Try to obtain the service credentials
            var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            // Read the template and parameter file contents
            JObject templateFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToTemplateFile);
            JObject parameterFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToParameterFile);

            // Create the resource manager client
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCreds);
            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            // Create or check that resource group exists
            EnsureResourceGroupExists(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation);

            // Start a deployment
            DeployTemplate(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, deploymentName, templateFileContents, parameterFileContents);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a JSON file from the specified path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathToJson">The full path to the JSON file</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON file contents</returns>
        private JObject GetJsonFileContents(string pathToJson)
        {
            JObject templatefileContent = new JObject();
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJson))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    templatefileContent = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    return templatefileContent;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that a resource group with the specified name exists. If it does not, will attempt to create one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupLocation">The resource group location. Required when creating a new resource group.</param>
        private static void EnsureResourceGroupExists(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string resourceGroupLocation)
        {
            if (resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CheckExistence(resourceGroupName) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating resource group '{0}' in location '{1}'", resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation));
                var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup();
                resourceGroup.Location = resourceGroupLocation;
                resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Using existing resource group '{0}'", resourceGroupName));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts a template deployment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="deploymentName">The name of the deployment.</param>
        /// <param name="templateFileContents">The template file contents.</param>
        /// <param name="parameterFileContents">The parameter file contents.</param>
        private static void DeployTemplate(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string deploymentName, JObject templateFileContents, JObject parameterFileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting template deployment '{0}' in resource group '{1}'", deploymentName, resourceGroupName));
            var deployment = new Deployment();

            deployment.Properties = new DeploymentProperties
            {
                Mode = DeploymentMode.Incremental,
                Template = templateFileContents,
                Parameters = parameterFileContents["parameters"].ToObject<JObject>()
            };

            var deploymentResult = resourceManagementClient.Deployments.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, deploymentName, deployment);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Deployment status: {0}", deploymentResult.Properties.ProvisioningState));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you wound up using the template deployment script. This final piece of code which I also found in the azure portal is what I used to deploy our servers. With a little modification I was able to deploy from github.

Comment: Hi, class `using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models` is not available in any Microsoft framework :( what to do ???.